# Oauth2 token call failing with "request is missing a required parameter"

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, x-www-form-urlencoded, invalid-request-uri

I'm trying to connect to the REST API using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`,
using the following parameters:

```
 private String tokenEndpoint = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token";
    private String client_id = "2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private String client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private String grant_type = "client_credentials";
    private String scope = "projects:read";
```

and finally get the following error:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Client credentials missing or malformed in both HTTP Authorization header and HTTP POST body."}

My code is:

```
package testRestAPI;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.TrustStrategy;


public class OAuthClient {

    private String tokenEndpoint = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token";
    private String client_id = "2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private String client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private String grant_type = "client_credentials";
    private String scope = "projects:read";
    

    public String callService()  {


        String result = null;

        try {

                        //My site is set as insecure, so I set the following setting
            TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

            SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                    .build();

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
                    .build();


            /* HTTPCLIENT AND HTTPPOST OOBJECT */
            //      HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(tokenEndpoint);

            /* AUTHENTICATION CREDENTIALS ENCODING */
            String base64Credentials = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((client_id + ":" 
                    + client_secret).getBytes());

            /* HEADER INFO */
            httpPost.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer " +  base64Credentials);
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            //      /* PROXY CONFIG */
            //              HttpHost target = new HttpHost("proxy", 8080, "http");
            //              RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(target).build();
            //              httpPost.setConfig(config);

            /* OAUTH PARAMETERS ADDED TO BODY */
            StringEntity input = null;
            try {
                input = new StringEntity("grant_type=" + grant_type + "&scope=" + scope);
                httpPost.setEntity(input);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /* SEND AND RETRIEVE RESPONSE */
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /* RESPONSE AS STRING */
            //      String result = null;
            try {
                result = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OAuthClient oauthClient = new OAuthClient();
        String res = oauthClient.callService();
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

and finally get the following error:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Client credentials missing or malformed in both HTTP Authorization header and HTTP POST body."}

In Postman the connection is made successfully.[Connection with Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YETti.png)

[link to Oauth provider Api Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhoP5.png)

Comment: What you are doing in Postman (send client credentials in body) does not match the Java where you are sending a Authorization Bearer header. Also, the token is being composed in the style of a Basic header, ie Base64 encode of client_id:client_secret - unusual. Can you add a link to the OAuth provider Api doc (or whichever std they claim) to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

Primarily, you are not including the client_id and client_secret in the form. I observed with Fiddlr that Postman sends all these fields on a submitted form.

Other changes to improve, but probably not required to fix the code are to:

- Remove the nonsense Authorization Bearer header. Postman does not
  send and doesn't  make sense to send one until a token has been
  received.
- Replaced the home-made form emulation and replaced with the standard
  `UrlEncodedFormEntity` passing a `List<NameValuePair>`. It adds the `"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` header to the request.

Try this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.http.Consts;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.ssl.TrustStrategy;


public class OAuthClient {

    private String tokenEndpoint = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token";
    private String client_id = "2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private String client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private String grant_type = "client_credentials";
    private String scope = "projects:read";
    

    public String callService()  {


        String result = null;

        try {

                        //My site is set as insecure, so I set the following setting
            TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

            SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
                    .build();

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(csf)
                    .build();


            /* HTTPCLIENT AND HTTPPOST OOBJECT */
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(tokenEndpoint);

            /* OAUTH PARAMETERS ADDED TO FORM */
            List<NameValuePair> form = new ArrayList<>();
            form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", grant_type));
            form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("scope", scope));
            form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", client_id)); // these two were missing
            form.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", client_secret));
            
            // UrlEncodedFormEntity is the standard way of building a firm submission
            // and it removes the need to manually add the "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(form, Consts.UTF_8);
            
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            /* SEND AND RETRIEVE RESPONSE */
            HttpResponse response = null;
            try {
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            /* RESPONSE AS STRING */
            //      String result = null;
            try {
                result = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OAuthClient oauthClient = new OAuthClient();
        String res = oauthClient.callService();
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```